# How to use space between and Text in Row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use space between to separate two Text widgets but none of mainAxisAlignment options works. 
[Screenshot of code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soqW6.png).

[image]

In the picture, you can see Text2 and Text3 are glued together I want them separated. First child in main Row needs to be expanded 1. Second (the problematic one) needs to be like expanded 0.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Text('Text1'),
        ),
        flex: 1,
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [Text('Text2'), Text('Text3')],
          ),
          Text('Long text Long text Long text'),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

so I realized you used `Expanded` widget for the first child but not for the second. Also, you need to add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to the `Row` widget. Below is a complete code for what you want to achieve.

```
Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Row(
        children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: Text('Text1'),
                ),
                flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                        Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                                Text('Text2'),
                                Text('Text3')
                            ],
                        ),
                        Text('Long text Long text Long text'),
                    ],
                ),
            )
        ],
    ),
)
```

[image: Desired outcome!]

Answer (score 0):

Use mainAxisAlignment to spaceBetween

```
 Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [Text('Text2'), Text('Text3')],
     ),
```

Comment: It doesn't work. None of the mainAxisAlignment options works. Maby is the way flutter calculate Text widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spacer()` between two `Text`.

```
Text("Text2"), 
Spacer(), 
Text("Text3")
```

Comment: This throws some layout error. I ended up using IntrinsicWidth on Column widget.

Comment: Try to avoid `IntrinsicWidth` as much as possible.

Comment: Read that in doc :) but really have no idea what use instead to get desired design.